# Personal blog vs Medium

Tags: seo, links, blog, articles

I would like to start a blog. Being a developer, I would like to write about new technologies and best practices. I plan to link articles with code repositories on my GitHub or to link my StackOverflow account, LinkedIn account, YouTube channel...

I was wandering which is better choice to gain bigger "popularity" of articles and to share SEO "reputation" of the blog with these accounts (StackOverflow, LinedIn, YouTube channel...). Are there some advantages of creating my personal blog application where I would post articles, versus creating an account in a platform like Medium and publish posts there?

Comment: "there some advantages of creating my personal blog application" Almost none, except to learn. There are more options than the one you list. You can use a full website allowing anyone to write, but you can also just register a domain name (that will work as your identity and as long as you keep control of it you can ensure stable links to your articles, etc.) and then host your content in any webhosting company that will offer packages of WordPress or other similar CMS to write your articles into. Many people do both (publishing on their own + copy on Medium for example).

Answer (score 5):

### The Correct Answer is...Both?

Everything should start on your website. So you should definitely create that. The advantage here is that you're creating your own place with a domain that is associated with content about you.

This is home base, where you live. All of the other places you post are spots you frequent.

From a content perspective, we want to cross post and link as much as we can. I call this *amplifying content*.

So you might first post on your site. Then you might share on your medium, [setting your website as the canonical](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033930293-Set-a-canonical-link).
Perhaps after that you put up a YouTube video talking about the topic. Internally link the matching content your site and your medium account in the description.

---

### E-A-T = SEO Reputation

As far as "SEO reputation" goes, what you're describing is [E-A-T](https://lilyray.nyc/e-a-t-expertise-authoritativeness-trustworthiness/). Google will understand who you are, and it will remember that you know your stuff.

I wrote an answer a while back talking about this where I go into [named entity association and Author Rank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/136893/122139). Definitely check out Bill Slawski's  content that I linked if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Always publish your original content through your website. Because your site **belongs to you**.

You can write what you want, design it the way you want, and combine it with any other element on your site the way you want.

After that, you should also send all the average messages on **Medium** site. You can import your message with one click using the "Import" feature of the **Medium**.

Because the medium has hundreds of thousands of readers. When you cross the media, your audience is already here. You can "borrow" by tapping their traffic.

If you first write on your website and then import to Medium site, you will get the best traffic of both worlds.